# ほうをかす lend a hou

Tags: grammar, kanji, katakana, kana, transcription

I was watching another 45 second video, same theme as the last one about 'Illegal uploads', but ran into some trouble with the above. I will post the entire subtitles for context purposes.

違法だよ！あげるくん

It's illegal! Ageru-kun

あげるくん遊ばないの？

Aren't you going to play?

昨日の番組をネットに上げてから

I'm uploading yesterday's program to the internet

またかー

This again?

今か

Now?/Today? (not sure which one...)

見られなかった人のために上げているんだよ

I'm uploading it for those who couldn't see it

違法

Illegal

え？

Huh?

それ「無断アップロード」って言って違法だから

That's called an "unauthorized upload" and its illegal

はい、はい、分かりました。

Yes, yes, I understand.

つかまるよ、マジで。

You will be caught, seriously.

2nd

違法だよ！あげるくん

It's illegal! Ageru-kun

うわっこの番組最高！

Wow! This show is the best!

SNSで拡散だな！

I'll Spread it on SNS!

トメ吉:

それはダメ。違法だから

Tomekichi:

That is not acceptable. Because it is illegal.

しーっ！いま録画中！

Shh! I'm in the process of recording!

それ「無断アップロード」って言うんだよ

That's called an "unauthorized upload"

みんなが喜ぶんだよ！返せよ！

It'll make everyone happy! Give it back!

つかまるよ、マジで。

You will be caught, seriously.

3rd

違法だよ！あげるくん

It's illegal! Ageru-kun

ドラマを録ってネットに上げるのは違法って言ったよね？

I said it was illegal to record dramas and upload them online, didn't I?

でもみんなのために僕は方を貸すのです

But I'm just loaning it to everyone (This is the hardest sentence for me, can't find 方を貸す, only 肩を貸す 1. to lend someone one's shoulder; to support with one's shoulder; to lend a hand; to come to someone's aid, but this one is pronounced kata wo kasu**)**

10年以下の懲役か1000万円以下の罰金、またはその両方。

10 years imprisonment and / or a fine of 10 million yen or more.

バレなきゃいいんじゃない

As long as no one finds out, it's fine

バレるから。それがネットだから。

Someone will find out. It is the internet, after all.

Comment: @Eiríkr Útlendi You are the best! Thanks for the help. That one was really making me pull my hairs out, until you came along!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that either you misheard, or if you've posted the text as seen, then whoever transcribed it misheard.

The key phrase here **isn't** 方【ほう】を貸【か】す ("to lend a way"?), which doesn't make sense, as you correctly note.  That rendering seems like a [mondegreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen), a goofy phrase based on mishearing something.

The phrase is instead probably supposed to be 法【ほう】を犯【おか】す ("to violate the law"), which is much more straightforward, and fits the context as well.